# How to save & retrieve NSdata into sqlite through FMDB

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7, fmdb

How can I save `NSData` into sqlite, I am using FMDB wrapper for saving data.

Below is the code which I have tried so far 

**For saving**

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:model.expertArray];; 
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into save_article values ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",
                       model.Id, model.title, model.earliestKnownDate, data, model.excerpt,model.image_url];
```

**For Retriving**

```
while([results next]) {
  NSData *data = [results dataForColumn:@"experts"];
        NSMutableArray *photoArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
 }
```

I have tried both datatype blob & text but no luck so far, can anybody guide me how to do it?

Comment: Generally NSData should be stored as a blob.  And, with a blob you pretty much must use bound parameters.  Otherwise the (non-ASCII) blob data will cause a corrupted insert statement to be generated.

Comment: I tried with blob also but that doesnt work

Comment: (BTW, if you're building your statements that way you're not really using FMDB, you'll only working around it.)

Comment: You must use bound parameters.  Simply inserting a blob with `stringWithFormat` results in a corrupted SQL statement.

Comment: Can you give example on bound parameters ?

Comment: What rmaddy said.  Though there are several ways to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below is the Snippet for all who may face the same issue while inserting `NSData` to Sqlite using FMDB.

In my Case I wanted to store `NSArray` in `Sqlite` So i first convert the `NSArray` into `NSData` & then store it in `Sqlite`.

**Converting NSArray into NSData**

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:YourNSarray];;
```

**Saving NSData into Sqlite**

```
[database executeQuery:@"insert into save_article values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", model.Id, model.title, model.earliestKnownDate, data, model.excerpt,model.image_url];
```

**Note:-** Don't build a query using `stringWithFormat`[below is the code which you should not use]:. Thanks to @rmaddy & @hotlicks  for pointing me to this :)

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into user values ('%@', %d)",
@"brandontreb", 25];
[database executeUpdate:query];
```

and now the last step i.e  retrieving **NSData back to NSArray**

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[database dataForColumn:@"yourcololumname"]];
```

Hope this will help the needy & beginner :)

Comment: What is "data" columns data type?

Comment: Use blob for  data columns

Comment: @DAMM108 I have tried this but it is not working for me even i have the data type blob. Is there any more clarification you can give ? Also, dont you think query should be like this Insert into user (coulmn1, 2,3) values(?,?,?)" ...

Answer (score 6):

Don't build a query using `stringWithFormat:`. This is a bad idea for several reasons.

Use the `executeQuery` method where you put a `?` for each value to be bound to the query.

Something like this:

```
[database executeQuery:@"insert into save_article values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", model.Id, model.title, model.earliestKnownDate, data, model.excerpt,model.image_url];
```

Comment: which datatype should i use then blob or text

Comment: Use a blob for `NSData`.

Comment: @rmaddy, can you please elaborate the reasons for not using stringWithFormat?

Comment: @EricChuang The problem is that if you use `stringWithFormat:`, the values may contain special characters that aren't properly escaped. This leads to bugs and crashes. It also can lead to SQL injection attacks (search on that term if you don't know what that is). By properly binding values you eliminate all of these issues.

Comment: @rmaddy i faced same issue for stringWithFormat: while inserting string like ex. That's. this ' is creating issue while inserting how to fix that?

Comment: the `'` needs to be escaped, in sqlite it's escaped with an apostrophe, so it ends up looking like this: `''` (2 apostrophes not a double quote) or you can use SQLite's built in formatters: `char *result = sqlite3_vmprintf("%Q", variadic params);`. `%q` and `%Q` are likely what you want.  sqlite has a few different sqlite3_*printf versions. As others noted, it's safer to just use statement binding then you don't need to worry about it. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html

Comment: So if I used to build the query like in your example, I have to pass the values in the order they are in table? @rmaddy

Comment: @Hemang The best solution is to list the column names in the SQL: `INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`. Then the values should be passed in the order listed in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: executeUpdate, not executeQuery