# How to save image in sqlite using FMDB in ios?

Tags: ios, image, sqlite, nsdata, fmdb

I want to save image in my database and retrieve it when i need them, i have tried all solutions which i get through searching

```
[database executeQuery:
@"INSERT INTO customerPresImage (cbFormFK, imageName, imagePath, imageData) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
cbFormPK, 
[[AllFormFields sharedManager].nameSaved objectAtIndex:i],
[[AllFormFields sharedManager].images objectAtIndex:i], 
[[AllFormFields sharedManager].actualImageData objectAtIndex:i]
];
```

---

```
[[AllFormFields sharedManager] actualImageData]
```

contains NSData object but when ever i try to execute my app got stuck at this point:

[image]

i have also tried to making that object archived but logically this doesnt make sense because i already have nsdata object in my array

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[[AllFormFields sharedManager].actualImageData objectAtIndex:i]];
```

P.S: I am using blob data type in sqlite. Please suggest me correction or if there is another way to get it done.

i have seen and acted upon these questions [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234237/how-to-save-retrieve-nsdata-into-sqlite-through-fmdb?rq=1)

[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454568/how-can-i-save-retrieve-an-image-bytes-to-sqlite-blob-using-fmdb)

Comment: the screenshot implies you have a memory management problem and try to access a pointer/variable not available anymore

Comment: but why it succeed when i remove column names and execute it. but nsdata object does not save in it

Answer (score 0):

Use

`[database executeUpdate:… ]` instead of
 *`[database executeQuery :… ]`*.

---

See `Executing Updates` at the [FMDB Website](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Here is the first line:

> Any sort of SQL statement which is not a SELECT statement qualifies as
>   an update.

Comment: Did that not good for me. Although i had sought out the way but this saving of image data isn't working for me idk why.

Comment: Do some error checking. If you don't know how: read the part about executing updates @ the FMDB Website, it's described there. Make sure the objects you're trying to insert are valid, non-nil objects. I think it can fail when an object is nil.